# Remote host "." was not found error

Tags: c#, .net, db2, database-connection

I am getting following error while trying to connect to DB2 database.

> SQL1336N  The remote host "." was not found.  SQLSTATE=08001

The DB2 Express is installed in my local machine and using command window I created some tables in the database.

What should be the hostname to overcome this error?

**CODE**

```
   string connectionString= @"Provider = IBMDADB2; Database = MYDATABASE; Hostname = .; Protocol = TCPIP; Port = 50000; Uid = xxx123; Pwd = dddd@454";
   OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection();
   myConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
   myConnection.Open();
```

Comment: have you tried localhost, . is a special alias for MSSQL i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Connection String**

```
"Provider = IBMDADB2; Database = TIMS; Hostname = localhost; Protocol = TCPIP; Port = 50010; Uid = myUserID; Pwd = myPassword";
```

Refer [No start database manager command was issued error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482339/no-start-database-manager-command-was-issued-error) also

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should try to set your hostname to your local ip or "localhost".

Comment: Thanks. I had some more challenges. I have put it as an answer.